# Equal height columns with absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list that has a bit of content and a button. The columns (LIs) will not always be the same height, but I want the button to always be at the bottom. I'm using the display: table / display: table-cell trick to keep the LIs the same height, however I can't get the button to align correctly. I want the button at the bottom, but I also want it to behave like the content does. Meaning I want it centered and to change it's width as the browser is resized.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattymess/BBuqY/

This is a snippet of code showing how I'm doing the equal height...

```
.rewards .rewards-chooser {
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.rewards .reward {
  width: 25%;
  border-left: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't changing `magin-left:-25%;` to `margin-left:-50%;` for `.rewards .reward .redeem` do this for you? Unless I've misunderstood..

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` in `.rewards .reward .redeem` class like this:

```
.rewards .reward .redeem {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*Just to knowledge: Your button is relative to something (your container), and not absolute.*

To set the buttons in the same line, you should to define a height for the container scope. Something like this:

```
.reward-description {
    height: 200px;
}
```

I made a clean example for you. To see, [click here (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9yxvp/).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that each block might not always be the same height because of different content. I don't want to force the block to be 400px tall when it only has 2 lines of copy. Basically, I wanted all the blocks to be as tall as the tallest block, which would have been defined by the amount of content in it. That's why I was using `display: table-cell`